# Strange animation when changing height constraint on a CollectionView (autolayout)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have a collectionView which I need to animate height changes for, so it expands up from the foot of the screen, & back down again. It's hard to explain what's going wrong so I've attached a recording of the simulator. The animation is fine for expanding, but very odd for the collapse - the content partially disappears as it animates, then reappears when it's done. The animation code is triggered during the scrollView 'scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)' delegate method, with logic to determine whether to collapse or expand. The expand animation, whose code is pretty much identical, works fine.

Animation code -

```
private func collapseTable() {
    guard self.isTableChangingSize == false else { return } // as the delegate method is triggered during the animation, we use a flag to prevent multiple collapse calls
    guard self.tableHeightConstraint.constant != self.tableCollapsedHeight else { return } // don't collapse if we're already collapsed

    self.isTableChangingSize = true
    self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableCollapsedHeight

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { _ in
        self.isTableChangingSize = false
    }
}
```

Here are a couple of videos of what's happening -
[Normal speed](https://youtu.be/n2tScL8nWVA)
[Slow motion](https://youtu.be/JBQK6L-UuPI)

Answer (score 1):

After far too long messing about trying different approaches, & tweaking everything, it seems that the problem was allowing scrolling during the animation block. If you set -

```
self.collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

before the animation block, and -

```
self.collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
```

in the completion, all is good.